# CSS Changes made, lost functionality

Tags: jquery, html, css, wordpress

I just have a question regarding a site that I'm working on,

http://sportsentertainmentattorney.com/

My problem is, I made some css changes in wordpress using the edit css page, specifically these changes.

```
@media (min-width: 360px) and (max-width: 959px) {
  .ciref.outline-outward.left {
    margin-left: 28%;
  }

  .right {
    margin-left: 28%;
  }

  #print_radio {
    word-wrap: break-word;
  }

  #blog-text-title {
    line-height: 36px;
    word-wrap: break-word;
  }

  #tony_media.custom_title1 {
    font-size: 52px !important;
    line-height: initial;
    padding: 1px 3px 3px !important;
  }

  .title2 .text {
    Margin-left: 24%;
  }

  .title2 h2 em {
    margin-top: 10px;
  }

  strong {
    line-height: initial;
  }
}
```

After these changes were made, half the site lost functionality in its mobile version. The beginning icons lose there clickable action before the resolution of 765, after they work fine. The slideshow does not work at all anymore unless the site is in desktop mode. I tried deleting my changes and reverting back but nothing has fixed it as of yet.

I would appreciate any help, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the problem is related to your browser cache, try reverting the changes and open the page with cleared browser cache (or a different browser)

Comment: I have tried, I've also used my phone to test the website, nothings working at the moment.

Comment: Ill check the link you posted :)

Comment: When I open the website in Chrome and scale down the website looks fine, exactly what part should have been damaged?

Comment: The main broken parts are , under "Why Choose Us" those 9 Icons should respond to a touch click creating a red border as it does in the desktop mode. Also that slideshow which consists of Allison strong and others, none of those links in that slideshow are clickable either.

Comment: When I inspect element in mobile version, the wrong class gets chosen, I think that might be the problem. Every part that doesn't work falls under the same class "h2#print_radio.front_h2" which it shouldn't be. I just don't know how I would go about testing that.